# Sending XMLRPC Request with python3

Tags: python-3.x, xml-rpc

i want to make a request with python and xmlrpc.

```
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy, datetime
import ssl
import hashlib

hash_object = hashlib.md5(b'USER*PASSWORD')

test = ServerProxy('https://IP/xml-rpc?de.vertico.starface.auth=%s' % hash_object.hexdigest(),
                             verbose=False, use_datetime=True, 
                             context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
print(test.Queue.getHistoryData({"queueName" : "Hauptgruppe","from" : "20161230T12:59:05", "to" : "20170701T12:59:05"}))
```

The body needs to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>Queue.getHistoryData</methodName>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value>
            <struct>
               <member>
                  <name>queueName</name>
                  <value>
                     <string>testIq</string>
                  </value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>from</name>
                  <value>
                     <string>20150701T12:59:05</string>
                  </value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>to</name>
                  <value>
                     <string>20160701T12:59:05</string>
                  </value>
               </member>
            </struct>
         </value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodCall>
```

But i keep getting following error as result. And i dont know how to fix it. Can someone please give me some help?

```
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: 'java.lang.ClassCastException : java.lang.String
cannot be cast to java.util.Date'>
```

Comment: Are you **certain** that the `from` and `to` values are supposed to be strings, *and* that their format is correct?

Comment: yeah, the body i posted here is the example from the manufacturers wiki. So the python code is correct?

Comment: Note that the `use_datetime` flag is obsolete; you want to use the `use_builtin_types=True` flag.

Comment: I **suspect** that they really want `<dateTime.iso8601>` tags. Try using `import datetime` and `"from": datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 12, 59, 5)` and `"to": datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 1, 12, 59, 5)` (and have `use_builtin_types=True` set).

Comment: that did it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error message, I suspect that you need to send `<dateTime.iso8601>` tags instead. Try sending `datetime` objects:

```
import datetime

test = ServerProxy(
    'https://IP/xml-rpc?de.vertico.starface.auth=%s' % hash_object.hexdigest(),
    verbose=False, use_builtin_types=True, 
    context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
print(test.Queue.getHistoryData({
    "queueName": "Hauptgruppe",
    "from" : datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 12, 59, 5),
    "to": datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 1, 12, 59, 5)}))
```

Note that I switched to using `use_builtin_types` as `use_datetime` is deprecated.